# Is there a JavaScript function like PHP‘s exit()?

Tags: javascript, exit

I need to stop my script. I don't want to write more code like `if(...) return false` because I will use it many times.

My English is poor. It's my first question on this site.  :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far. Please post it here or please elaborate on your question.

Comment: It sounds like you want to just kill everything that's running without having to return from every function in the stack? I guess you could throw an exception, which will stop everything (unless the code is in a try ... catch block). That's very messy though, and it will appear as a JavaScript error in the user's browser.

Comment: document.write("string");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to exit ALL scopes of your script, you could throw an exception and catch it at the outer scope of your script ;)
This imposes, that you adapt your exception handling.

Please note: It is better to write your program in such way, that the following is NOT necessary!

```
function ExitException() {}

try { //Do your script-stuff here

  Foo();

  //and do this at any place where you wish to exit:
  throw new ExitException;
}
catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof ExitException) //This is an Exit. All fine.
    console.log("Exit");
  else //Pass Exception to the Browser
    throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can simply write `return false;` to do so.

Comment: OP has already told that he doesn't want to use `return false;`. (This is an example, how people answers / upvotes answers without reading the question properly. )